# RVM not working in all terminals?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I installed RVM and Ruby and executed `ruby -v`. It executed correctly by showing the version but when I try it in a new terminal it is returning an error:

```
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

If I run `source /home/prabhakaran/.rvm/scripts/rvm` in each terminal I open it is running.

What is the problem, and how can I solve it?

Comment: The `rvm` installation makes changes to the shell start-up script. Are you logging in as the same user in the new terminal? If you want it to work for all users, there's a particular procedure for the installation described in the `rvm` install documentation.

Comment: Ya logging as same user in terminal then too not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure your terminal starts up a login shell for `rvm` to work.  Are you using a GNOME terminal by any chance?  By default, those do not start with a login shell, but you can change that under [profile settings](http://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal).